# Как запретить движение объекта в обратную сторону Unity 3D?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Cоздаю гоночную игру на Unity. Возникла надобность создания проверки на правильное направление движения автомобиля. Каким образом можно создать данную проверку?
Сделать проверку через координаты не получилось так как гоночная трасса имеет различные повороты и координаты часто уходят в разные значения(как в минусовые так и в плюсовые значения)

Comment: Для начала нужно определить вообще что такое езда в неправильном направлении. Для этого нужно разбить карту на секторы и реализовать логику что игрок находясь в этой вот коробке должен ехать в такую-то сторону. Если игрок отдаляется от эталонной точки направления, значит он едет не в ту сторону. А если приближается то всё ок.

Comment: Вот пример файла эталонных точек. https://ibb.co/wdxxT0M хочу заметить что каждая последующая точка находиться в следующем секторе. И как только игрок до неё добирается у него включается следующая. А дальше считаешь Penalty. Скажем раз в 3-5 сек.  Если игрок 3 раза подряд удалился от эталонной точки, то просто сбрасываешь его обратно на трассу.

Comment: Разница векторов сравнивается через скалярное произведение нормализованных значений этих векторов `Vector3.Dot(a.normalized, b.normalized)` в результате чего получает значение от `-1`(ровно в противоположные) до `1`(ровно одинаковые).

Comment: Можете чуть подробнее расписать код? Я новичок и не сильно разбираюсь пока что во всём этом